# Docker build dependent on host Ubuntu version not on the actual Docker File

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-20.04

I'm facing an issue with my docker build.

I have a dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM python:3.6


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libav-tools 
....
```

The issue I'm facing is that I'm getting this error when building on **ubuntu:20.04 LTS**

```
E: Package 'libav-tools' has no installation candidate
```

I made some research and found out that `ffmpeg` should be a replacement for `libav-tools`

```
FROM python:3.6


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg 
....
```

I tried again without any issue.

but when I tried to build the same image with `ffmpeg` on **ubuntu:16.04 xenial**  I'm getting a message that

```
E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
```

after that, I replace the `ffmpeg` with  `libav-tools`  and it worked on ubuntu:16.04

I'm confused now why docker build is dependant on the host ubuntu version that I'm using and not the actual dockerfile.

shouldn't  docker build  be coherent whatever the ubuntu version I'm using.

Comment: I hope you don't have a cached image of python:3.6 on any of the nodes? I would suggest do a latest pull as well

Comment: After I tried to delete the `python:3.6` image and pull it again. it fixed the error I think I had an old version of python 3.6 that had an old version of debian. Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the the existing image and pull it again. Seems you have a old image which may have a different base OS and that is why you are seeing the issue